# Running python file on Google Colaboratory from terminal

Tags: javascript, python, terminal, google-colaboratory

I have some large files which I want to run on Google Colaboratory from my terminal by specifying the file name or by sending a request to the Google colab server. How can I do that ?

PS: The files are run one by one using a javascript file on which I have no control. Their running process is all handled by that js file and I can't modify it. Is there any way to send these files on the colaboratory and run it there ?

I would appreciate if the solution you give also has a documentation URL so that I can refer to it future if similar need arises.